# php str_replace in text

Tags: php, str-replace

I have templates in DB for example client choose this template

```
$var = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
this is [Dateiname] 
its your [Format]
your alang [Ausgangssprache]
your zlang [Zielsprache]
readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is";
```

Need to replace `[Dateiname] [Format] [Ausgangssprache] [Zielsprache]`

I have 3 posts and in my posts DB i have `Dateiname,Format,Ausgangssprache,Zielsprache` filds

When I select that filds for example

```
$result="";
for($i = 0; i<count($posts); $i++)
    {
        $replaceText = array(
                             '[Dateiname]',
                             '[Format]',
                             '[Ausgangssprache]',
                             '[Zielsprache]',
                             );
        $replacePost = array(
                             $filename[$i], 
                             $filetype[$i],
                             $ausgangsspracheOne['de'],  
                             $zeilspracheOne['de'],
                             );
        $result.= str_replace($needReplace, $replacePost, $var);  
    }
```

My result shows me this text 3 times for example:

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
>       **[post1]
>       [titel1]
>       [desc1]
>       [year1]**
>
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
>       **[post2]
>       [titel2]
>       [desc2]
>       [year2]**
>
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
>       **[post3]
>       [titel3]
>       [desc3]
>       [year3]**

I need it like this, is it possible?

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
>
> ```
> [post1]
> [titel1]
> [desc1]
> [year1]
>
> [post2]
> [titel2]
> [desc2]
> [year2]
>
> [post3]
> [titel3]
> [desc3]
> [year3]
> ```

Comment: why do you use str_replace? Is it required?

Answer (score 1):

You should separate `$var` into the parts that should be shown once and the template that needs to be replaced for each entry.

```
$var_before = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the \n";
$var_template = "[Dateiname]
[Format]
[Ausgangssprache]
[Zielsprache]

";
$var_after = "readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is";
```

Then you can use only `$var_template` in the loop.

```
$result = $var_before;
$replaceText = array(
                     '[Dateiname]',
                     '[Format]',
                     '[Ausgangssprache]',
                     '[Zielsprache]',
                     );
for($i = 0; i<count($posts); $i++)
    {
        $replacePost = array(
                             $filename[$i], 
                             $filetype[$i],
                             $ausgangsspracheOne['de'],  
                             $zeilspracheOne['de'],
                             );
        $result .= str_replace($needReplace, $replacePost, $var_template);
    }
$result .= $var_after;
```

Comment: But how can i finde where  $var_before and where $var_after when i get this text into DB ?

Comment: You need to redesign the database so it has separate fields for the repeated template and the one-time prefix and suffix.

Comment: Or you could put a delimiter into `$var` that tells it where the repeated section is, and use `explode()` to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want, but could you use something like this?
If you provided more code and more details I could provide better solution.

```
$var = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the";
echo $var . "<br>"
$result="";
for($i = 0; i<count($posts); $i++)
{
 print $filename[$i] . " " .$filetype[$i] . " " . $ausgangsspracheOne['de']. " " .$zeilspracheOne['de']."<br>";

 }
```

Comment: For first i need to finde in that text this
`[Dateiname]
[Format]
[Ausgangssprache]
[Zielsprache] ` words after change

Comment: could you post your complete script? I can't figure what you can't do and what you want to do. The values you want to find have to come from your db.

Comment: I have text templates in DB and in that text i have some tags for example **My name is [Name]** Where [Name] tag. I need find in that text this tag [Name] and replace it in real name for example **Andy**

Comment: then use Barmar's answer